# Selecting different records for each member of a table SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery, mariadb

I have a database with two tables, matches and teams. The teams table is simple, it contains a field with a list of 20 teams. The matches table records the matches played between teams. The fields are as follows (with an example of data):

```
 +------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+
 | Week | HomeTeam | AwayTeam    | HomeScore | AwayScore | Result | MATCHID |
 +------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+
 |    1 | Stoke    | Aston Villa |         0 |         1 | A      |     151 |
 +------+----------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------+---------+
```

My question is, how can I return useful data from this in the form of points earned, etc, for each team? I can calculate points earned for a *given team* but not for all teams in a table. For instance, I can calculate the points for Liverpool with

```
SELECT
 (SELECT COUNT(matches.Result)*3 
   FROM matches 
   WHERE (HomeTeam='Liverpool' AND Result='H') OR (AwayTeam='Liverpool' AND Result='A'))+
 (SELECT COUNT(matches.Result) 
   FROM matches 
   WHERE (HomeTeam='Liverpool' OR AwayTeam='Liverpool') AND Result='D');
```

which will spit out an output of '21'. But what I actually want is a list of teams (as defined by the 'teams' table) and the points earned by each. How do I go about getting that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to get each individual's teams statistics.  Then you can use conditional aggregation to get your desired results.

Here's an example with `SUM` and `CASE`:

```
SELECT
  t.teamname,
  3*SUM(
    CASE WHEN t.teamname = m.hometeam AND m.result = 'H' THEN 1
         WHEN t.teamname = m.awayteam AND m.result = 'A' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END) + 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN m.result = 'D' THEN 1
         ELSE 0
    END)
FROM teams t
  JOIN matches m ON t.teamname in (hometeam,awayteam)
GROUP BY 
  t.teamname
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c4fcf/1)

Comment: OK this makes sense. I will need to play around with it a bit first b/c I am getting syntax errors

Comment: Forgot to say - Thanks!

Comment: @user2784067 -- np, glad it helps.